# Not able to import pipelines from tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'torch.distributed'

This is the error while im trying to import pipeline from transformer.
My tensorflow is upraded to latesr version 2.11.0 and i am running this on windows 11 on visual code using python 3.10

Detailed Error if this helps:

```
File c:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py:1093, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1092 try:
-> 1093     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1094 except Exception as e:

File c:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File c:\Users\varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\__init__.py:48
     40 from ..utils import (
...
   1097         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1098     ) from e
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the complete traceback error with the last error code line. However, I am successfully able to import pipelines from transformers in **VS code** which I installed using **Anaconda Navigator**.(Check the image below)

Could you please try again by installing the `transformers` as below before importing the pipeline from it as below:

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import pipelines
```

[image]

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.